# Difference SQLSERVER and MSSQLSERVER services

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two SQL Server services in Sql Server Configuration Manager: SQLEXPRESS and MSSQLSERVER. I have no idea what the differences are. I think that SQLEXPRESS is the free version, but I don't know how I got it and I can't remove it either because it doesn't show up in remove programs.

But here's where it gets weird: I installed SQL Server Enterprise, and during installation I specified a local user (SQLServices) to be used for all SQL Server services. Okay, so this worked for SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER) and SQL Server Integration Services10.0 (MSSQLSERVER), they are running under this user. But SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) does NOT run and gives an error that it can't connect/time out etc., and SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) runs, but under NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. I stopped this, and tried to run the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER), but it keeps timing out on me. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that SQLEXPRESS is the free version. Not sure why it wouldn't show up in the list of programs to remove.

More than likely, SQLEXPRESS being present or running has nothing to do with trouble you are having with SQL Ent; they can run side-by-side as separate instances (barring any misconfiguration which would explicitly prevent it - which would likely have to be done purposefully)

NETWORK SERVICE is, I believe, the default that SQLEXPRESS will run under.

As for why SQL Ent is not running; exactly what error(s) are you getting? Have you checked the logs? It's possible the user in question does not have all the rights or permissions needed to run SQL Server.

Comment: The error is as follows: eventNo 7000. The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service failed to start due to the following error: 
SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) is not a valid Win32 application. My machine is windows 7, 64 bit. I did install sql server enterprise 64bit.
Also, when I change the password on the SQL Service (MSSQLSERVER), it says Access Denied [0x80070005].

Comment: Hmmm... that type of error seems to typically be caused by the service's entry somehow not correctly pointing to the executable. Can you view the entry in Services and verify that the path it is executing is correct? It should be contained in parenthesis if there are any spaces in the path too, btw.

Comment: This is the path to the executable: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sMSSQLSERVER

Comment: OK, that looks correct to me. Does that file exist, and do you know if it's possibly corrupted in some way? You could actually execute it directly to test that.

Comment: I installed it yesterday, nothing came up as error. The file does exist in that directory. BUT... I just noticed it's in the folder Program Files instead of Program Files(x86). This could explain why it says "Not a valid win32 application". But if this is it, how can I get the files to the Program Files (x86) directory?

Comment: You installed the 64 bit version, so it should not be in the `Program Files (x86)` directory. That message does seem specific to 32-bit applications, but I do not believe that there is any difference there; it says the same thing even if the program should be a 64-bit one.

Comment: In fact, I don't think 64-bit Windows would care if you were loading a 64 or 32 bit application there, and I *think* those different directory structures are merely for the sake of organization; I'm fairly sure I've copied 32-bit binaries into folders in the 64-bit folder tree before out of habit, and it made no difference at all.

Comment: Wow, then the only lead I thought I was onto is out... So, you have any ideas as to what it might be?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't. Hopefully someone else will come up with something!